# Creating optimal path between two spaces with point features in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

For my masters thesis I have mapped out all the green roofs in a city and I am trying to see if they can be used to connect two habitats. The two habitats are on opposite sides of the city and the green roofs are situated between them. I want to know the shortest route a pollinator would take when travelling form roof to roof to reach the other habitat. The pollinator has to travel to a nearby roof rather than traveling in a straight line toward the other habitat. I have included pictures from Microsoft paint to help illustrate this. (sorry for the quality).

[image: Green circles are the habitats and black dots are the green roofs.]
[image: I would like to create a path like this where the pollinator travels to the nearest green roof in the direction of the other habitat.]
[image: I do not want this because although it is the shortest path, the distance between each roof is too long.]

Comment: If you have Spatial Analyst available, the Distance Toolset might be helpful: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/connect-regions-with-the-optimal-network.htm

Comment: If you use the points to construct a TIN, in the absence of any other weighting surface, the TIN segments can be used to generate a path.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic example of a [Dijkstra algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).  I see that there is Python code [posted here](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-blog/finding-the-shortest-route-using-dijkstra-s/ba-p/884058) along with a detailed explanation on generating a shortest path from a graph using ArcGIS tools.  You would need  to first [generate the TIN](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/data/tin/create-a-tin-surface.htm) from some point data (green roofs and points representing habitat) in a Euclidean coordinate system and [export out the TIN edges](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/tin-edge.htm) to a feature class as Vince states. It looks like you will also need to generate a feature class for your start area and your end area.

I know you didn't ask for it but it looks like QGIS supports a Dijkstra's algorithm as well.  [See here for the QGIS approach](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html).